# Navigation Issue - Joomla

Tags: joomla

I'm having an issue where I cannot get my sub nav to hide until on Hover. I assume I accidentally just deleted some kind of css that I need, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what I did.

The link to the dev site is: http://fallriverbenefits.com/dev/

Comment: Which one is the "sub nav" ?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear - I meant the piece under the main navigation. So right now it's just the 'blog' page.

Comment: Have you tried anything? In terms of writing css.

Comment: I actually figured it out. I was missing a piece that told the li what to do on hover. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding this to the css:

```
  .nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: inherit;
  }

  .nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
  }

  .nav li ul li {
    display: block;
  }
```